# Ocultar div si elige la misma opcion jquery

Tags: html, jquery

tengo lo siguiente quiero mostrar lo que se selecciono pero si lo vuelven a seleccionar que se oculte

```js
$('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var text = $(this).attr('name');
        $('.filter-ative .filters').append('<button class="filter">' + text + '</button>');         
    } else{
        $('.filter').remove(); 
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="blanco">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="azul">

<div class="filter-ative">
  <div class="filters"></div>
</div>
```

me funciona a la mitad, me salen las opciones que coloque, pero al desmarcar una casilla me quita todo por que el remove esta a la clase general filter, entonces mi pregunta es, ¿Como podria hacer para que solo se oculte la opcion a la que desmarco la casilla?

Answer (score 1):

Bien, decidí dejarte una respuesta basada en la respuesta de @JhonMaldonado *ya que él tiene razón en que debes agregar un `id` a cada botón*, pero agregando las correcciones que menciono en el comentario, *agrego `type="checkbox"` a los `input` y separo por comas las clases en `js`*.

Si ejecutas el `snippet`, verás que se obtiene el resultado que esperas.

```js
$('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var text = $(this).attr('name'); // Declaramos en esta parte la variable text, ya que nos servirá como ID también
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.filter-ative, .filters').append('<button id="'+ text +'" class="filter">' + text + '</button>'); // Añadimos el nuevo ID
    } else{
        $('#'+text).remove(); // Eliminas el elemento que tenga ese ID
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="blanco">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="azul">

<div class="filters"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que puedo ver, lo que debes hacer es agregar un `id` único a cada botón que vas agregando, por ejemplo, el `id` podría ser tu atributo `name`.

Quedaría algo así:

```js
$('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var text = $(this).attr('name'); // Declaramos en esta parte la variable text, ya que nos servirá como ID también
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.filter-ative .filters').append('<button id="'+ text +'" class="filter">' + text + '</button>'); // Añadimos el nuevo ID
    } else{
        $('#'+text).remove(); // Eliminas el elemento que tenga ese ID
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="checkbox" name="blanco">
<input class="checkbox" name="azul">

<div class="filters"></div>
```

Comment: Con un par de correcciones creo que funcionaría... a los `input` debes agregarle `type="checkbox"` y en esta línea de `jQuery` : `$('.filter-ative .filters').append...` debes agregar una coma para separar las dos clases, así: `$('.filter-ative, .filters').append...`. Si modificas estas dos cosas, harás que el `snippet` funcione y te otorgaré mi voto.

Comment: .filter-ative es el padre de .filters por eso la puse asi para especificar mejor

Comment: lo coloque asi como mencionas, pero no me funciono, al darle un console.log no sale como tal el nombre del input, sale es un objeto vacio